# Solution Verification Solve the equation $\frac{38-11x}{6}=\{\frac{2x+1}{6}\}+\{\frac{x+17}{3}\}$ in the set of real numbers

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

*question*

Solve the equation $\frac{38-11x}{6}=\{\frac{2x+1}{6}\}+\{\frac{x+17}{3}\}$ in the set of real numbers.

*my idea*

Because ${a}$ is between $1$ and $0$ we can say that $0\leq\frac{38-11x}{6}<2$

after some processing, we can say that

$\frac{38}{11}\geq x>\frac{26}{11}$

Also we know that $x=[x]+\{x\}$ so we can write the equality as

$[\frac{2x+1}{6}]+[\frac{x+17}{3}]=\frac{15x-3}{6}\in Z$

which means that $15x-3=6k => 5x=2k+1$, which basically means that $x$ is even.

(*) Using @Robert Israel's idea we can write that

$[\frac{2x+1}{6}]$ can be $0$ or $1$ and $[\frac{x+17}{3}]$ can be only $6$.

Taking each case we get that $x=\frac{13}{5}$ or $3$ but the thing is that $x=\frac{13}{5}$ isn't working if we substitute x in the main equality.

Can you please tell me if my idea is ok and where I was wrong?

I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Those bounds on $x$ leave only a few possibilities for $\lfloor (2x+1)/6 \rfloor$ and $\lfloor (x+17)/3 \rfloor$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I edited my question using your idea

Comment: So if $\lfloor (2x+1)/6 \rfloor = 0$ and $\lfloor (x+17)/3 \rfloor = 6$, what is
$\{((2x+1)/6\} + \{(x+17)/3 \}$?  You should an equation you can solve for $x$.
Check whether the solution works.  Then try the case   $\lfloor (2x+1)/6 \rfloor = 1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I did this and the only solution I got is $x=3$. Is it right? Also, thank you for helping me!

Comment: Well, when $x=\frac{13}{5}$, $[\frac{2x+1}{6}]=1$, thus failing the equation.

Comment: @LeoJi This means the only solution is 3?

Comment: @Ionela Buciu Yep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\mathrm{38}−\mathrm{11}{x}}{\mathrm{6}}=\left\{\frac{\mathrm{2}{x}+\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{6}}\right\}+\left\{\frac{{x}+\mathrm{17}}{\mathrm{3}}\right\} \\ $$
$$\left[\frac{\mathrm{2}{x}+\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{6}}\right]+\left[\frac{{x}+\mathrm{17}}{\mathrm{3}}\right]=\frac{\mathrm{5}{x}−\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{2}}\in{N} \\ $$
$$\frac{\mathrm{38}−\mathrm{11}{x}}{\mathrm{6}}=\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{2}\right) \\ $$
$$\frac{\mathrm{5}{x}−\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{2}}=\left(\frac{\mathrm{119}}{\mathrm{22}};\frac{\mathrm{179}}{\mathrm{22}}\right] \\ $$
$$\frac{\mathrm{5}{x}−\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{2}}=\left\{\mathrm{6},\mathrm{7},\mathrm{8}\right\} \\ $$
$${x}=\left\{\cancel{\frac{\mathrm{13}}{\mathrm{5}}},\mathrm{3},\cancel{\frac{\mathrm{17}}{\mathrm{5}}}\right\} \\ $$

Comment: Only 3 satisfied it...